# How to do this in Laravel, subquery where in update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, subquery

How can I make this query in Laravel 5.2:

```
UPDATE product p
    SET price = ( SELECT price FROM product_price WHERE product_id = p.id AND price > 0 AND inventory > 0 AND active = 1 ORDER BY price desc limit 1)
    SET discounts = ( SELECT discount FROM product_price WHERE product_id = p.id AND price > 0 AND inventory > 0 AND active = 1 ORDER BY price desc limit 1)
    WHERE
    product_state = 1
```

how can I run this with db?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Raw Expressions for this kind of complex queries. Here is the reference with example on Official Laravel Doc:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: can you define which line of this document is my answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see your exact DB schema, and some data, to confirm, but the following should be on the right track:

```
use DB; // Ensure we have access to the DB facade

$result = DB::table('product')
    ->where('product_state', '=', 1)
    ->update([
        'price'     => DB::raw('(SELECT price FROM product_price WHERE product_id = product.id AND price > 0 AND inventory > 0 AND active = 1 ORDER BY price desc limit 1)'),
        'discounts' => DB::raw('(SELECT discount FROM product_price WHERE product_id = product.id AND price > 0 AND inventory > 0 AND active = 1 ORDER BY price desc limit 1)')
    ]);
```

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syn
  tax to use near 'SELECT price FROM product_price WHERE product_id = product.id AND price > 0 AND ' at line 1

Comment: Added the missing parenthesis to the answer. Should update as expected now.